# QT Application segmentation fault on exit when using std::unique_ptr for the QMainWindow

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, segmentation-fault, c++14

I should clarify first, my question is, why does the segfault happen in the case where I use a `std::unique_ptr` but it doesn't when I change the code to use new and delete? I don't really have an issue here, since the segfault is fixed and I know I'm properly cleaning things up with new and delete. I just want to know why I couldn't use a `std::unique_ptr`.

If I create my `QMainWindow` instance in a `std::unique_ptr` and my `MainWindow` creates a child window (e.g. opening a `QComboBox` or `ToolTip`), my application will segfault on exit. In this case, if my `MainWindow` does not create any child windows, there is no segfault.

If I manage my `QMainWindow` instance myself with new and delete, there is no segfault regardless of whether or not I create a child window.

This is my main, it simply calls `run` on my `Bridge` class that handles creating the instance of my `MainWindow` class and starting it.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Bridge bridge(argc, argv);
    bridge.run(); // Handles starting the main window
}
```

**This is a shortened version of my `Bridge` class that results in a segfault (using std::unique_ptr I get a segfault on exit):**

```
class Bridge::IMPL {
public:
    IMPL(int& argc, char ** argv) : 
        mainwindow(), isRunning(true), app(argc, argv) {}
    ~IMPL() = default;
public:
    std::unique_ptr<MainWindow> mainwindow;
    bool isRunning;
    QApplication app;
};

Bridge::Bridge(int& argc, char ** argv) :
    pImpl(make_unique<IMPL>(argc, argv)) {

    pImpl->mainwindow.reset(new MainWindow(this));
}
```

**This is the Bridge class with no segfault (slightly modified to remove the `std::unique_ptr` and instead use new and delete. This version of the `Bridge` class DOES NOT CRASH):**

```
class Bridge::IMPL {
public:
    IMPL(int& argc, char ** argv) : 
        mainwindow(nullptr), isRunning(true), app(argc, argv) {}
    ~IMPL() {
        if (mainwindow) {
            delete mainwindow;
        }
    }
public:
    MainWindow* mainwindow;
    bool isRunning;
    QApplication app;
};

Bridge::Bridge(int& argc, char ** argv) :
    pImpl(make_unique<IMPL>(argc, argv)) {

    pImpl->mainwindow= new MainWindow(this);
}
```

**This is the back-trace when a segfault would happen:**

*Also there is a weird print-out about `QBasicTimer` that doesn't get printed after I changed the code to use new and delete instead of `std::unique_ptr`*

```
QBasicTimer::start: QBasicTimer can only be used with threads started with QThread

Thread 1 "application" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fffe75bf2e2 in ?? () from /home/user/Qt/5.9/gcc_64/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fffe75bf2e2 in ?? () from /home/user/Qt/5.9/gcc_64/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
#1  0x00007fffe75bf5c4 in ?? () from /home/user/Qt/5.9/gcc_64/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
#2  0x00007fffe75b9669 in QXcbConnection::removeWindowEventListener(unsigned int) () from /home/user/Qt/5.9/gcc_64/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
#3  0x00007fffe75ceafa in QXcbWindow::destroy() () from /home/user/Qt/5.9/gcc_64/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
#4  0x00007fffe75cec07 in QXcbWindow::~QXcbWindow() () from /home/user/Qt/5.9/gcc_64/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
#5  0x00007fffe43ce2ee in ?? () from /home/user/Qt/5.9/gcc_64/plugins/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-glx-integration.so
#6  0x00007ffff4b56f46 in QWindowPrivate::destroy() () from /home/user/Qt/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5
#7  0x00007ffff534ecd7 in QWidgetPrivate::deleteTLSysExtra() () from /home/user/Qt/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#8  0x00007ffff53524d8 in QWidget::destroy(bool, bool) () from /home/user/Qt/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#9  0x00007ffff53598b0 in QWidget::~QWidget() () from /home/user/Qt/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#10 0x00007ffff541ae7a in ?? () from /home/user/Qt/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#11 0x00007ffff4580b83 in QObjectPrivate::deleteChildren() () from /home/user/Qt/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#12 0x00007ffff5359894 in QWidget::~QWidget() () from /home/user/Qt/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#13 0x00007ffff540eac9 in QComboBox::~QComboBox() () from /home/user/Qt/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#14 0x00007ffff4580b83 in QObjectPrivate::deleteChildren() () from /home/user/Qt/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#15 0x00007ffff5359894 in QWidget::~QWidget() () from /home/user/Qt/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#16 0x00007ffff5359ab9 in QWidget::~QWidget() () from /home/user/Qt/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#17 0x00007ffff4580b83 in QObjectPrivate::deleteChildren() () from /home/user/Qt/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#18 0x00007ffff5359894 in QWidget::~QWidget() () from /home/user/Qt/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#19 0x00007ffff5359ab9 in QWidget::~QWidget() () from /home/user/Qt/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#20 0x00007ffff4580b83 in QObjectPrivate::deleteChildren() () from /home/user/Qt/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#21 0x00007ffff5359894 in QWidget::~QWidget() () from /home/user/Qt/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#22 0x0000000000421ed4 in MainWindow::~MainWindow() ()
#23 0x0000000000421f0e in MainWindow::~MainWindow() ()
#24 0x0000000000421698 in std::default_delete<MainWindow>::operator()(MainWindow*) const ()
#25 0x0000000000421171 in std::unique_ptr<MainWindow, std::default_delete<MainWindow> >::~unique_ptr() ()
#26 0x000000000042191c in Bridge::IMPL::~IMPL() ()
#27 0x0000000000421942 in std::default_delete<Bridge::IMPL>::operator()(Bridge::IMPL*) const ()
#28 0x0000000000421387 in std::unique_ptr<Bridge::IMPL, std::default_delete<Bridge::IMPL> >::~unique_ptr() ()
#29 0x0000000000420cb0 in Bridge::~Bridge() ()
#30 0x0000000000421c41 in main ()
```

It should also be noted that this `QApplication` is run using a while loop and calls to `app.processEvents()` rather than calling `exec()`. I realize that's not the best way to do it, however this app is part of another application that polls for events from somewhere else and since the nature of this application is more "proof-of-concept" than anything else, I wanted to keep it simple by having it all in one thread. See below for a snippet of my run method:

```
while (isRunning()) {
    poller.poll(25);
    app.processEvents();
}
```

**EDIT:**

In my constructor for `MainWindow` the `this` I'm passing is not being set as the parent (the parent is `nullptr`):

header:

```
class MainWindow: public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    class BridgeInterface{
    public:
        // Some pure virtual methods here
    };

    explicit MainWindow(BridgeInterface* interface, QWidget* parent = nullptr);

// some more stuff...

private:
    class IMPL;
    std::unique_ptr<IMPL> pImpl;
};
```

source:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(BridgeInterface* interface, QWidget* parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent), pImpl(make_unique<IMPL>()) {

    pImpl->ui->setupUi(this);
    pImpl->bridgeInterface = interface;

    // Connect slots and stuff
}
```

Comment: `pImpl(make_unique<IMPL>(argc, argv))` Looks very suspect.  `IMPL` does try to delete the pointer does it?

Comment: Destructor implementation? What does it do? How are those child widgets instantiated?

Comment: pImpl is defined as a `std::unique_ptr<IMPL>` in the `Bridge` header. From the C++ documentation: `std::make_unique` "Constructs an object of type T and wraps it in a std::unique_ptr."

Comment: The child widgets are handled for me. I designed the MainWindow in QT creator and added a `QComboBox`. I have a CMake file where I do this:
`QT5_WRAP_CPP(mainwindow_moc ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/MainWindow.hh)`
`QT5_WRAP_UI(mainwindow_ui ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/MainWindow.ui)`

Comment: see edits. Also the `delete mainwindow` is from the code that does not segfault. The code that segfaults is the code where I use the unqiue_ptr and therefore I'm not deleting it myself.

Comment: If you suspect double-delete, then Valgrind is the tool of first resort - it will normally give you a stack trace from both `delete` calls.

Comment: just remove `this` in `reset`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your class, QApplication's destructor is being called before your mainwindow is destroyed. That's because class variables are initalized in the order they're listed, then destroyed in the opposite order.

If you move `QApplication app;` so it's the first variable in the class, its destructor will be called last, AFTER mainwindow is destroyed, which is the correct behavior.

The reason it works when you delete it explicitly is that you're deleting `mainwindow` via the IMPL's destructor. ~IMPL() runs before the class variable destructors are run, resulting in mainwindow being destroyed first.

Comment: This fixed my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Don't delete `MainWindow` after deleting `QApplication` instance. You need to somehow manage initialization and destruction order.

```
QApp::ctor Window::ctor Window::dtor QApp::dtor
```

Possible solution: destroy `MainWindow` directly inside `Bridge::~Bridge`

P.S. you don't need to pass `int argc` via reference.

P.P.S. about processEvents() - you may create a separated thread and run your Qt part there. It is OK to use GUI not from main thread, ofc if you know, what you are doing :). Main rule - QApplication instance and all GUI should be created from one thread

Comment: So solution is just to move `app(argc, argv)` at the beginning of the initalisation list, excelent spot.

on the PS I'm not 100% sure you can, from http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#QApplication: "the data referred to by argc and argv must stay valid for the entire lifetime of the QApplication object." if you pass argc by value and it gets deleted it might be trouble

Comment: @Dmitry QApplication takes argc by reference `QApplication(int &argc, char **argv)`

Comment: @StephenPape it doesn't matter :)

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to tell for sure given you did not post code for MainWindow but I'd say you are deleting mainwindow twice.

`pImpl->mainwindow= new MainWindow(this);` if `this` is a parent it will delete MainWindow automatically upon destruction and same thing will do the unique_ptr

Either use raw pointers and rely on Qt's parent-child cleanup or use smart pointers and do not pass a parent to MainWindow

Comment: Sorry about that. Yeah, in this case, `this` is not a parent. I'll post an update to the question. Also the code you're referencing is the version that does not segfault. The version that segfaults is the one where i use a `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: I updated the question with a snippet of my `MainWindow` header and source file. I hope that helps. The parent of my `MainWindow` class is `nullptr`

Comment: could you try replacing `std::unique_ptr` with `QScopedPointer<MainWindow,QScopedPointerDeleteLater>` and see if it still segfaults?

Comment: @IlBeldus `QScopedPointerDeleteLater` will cause memory leak, if it will be invoked after stop of an event loop.